# ¿Cómo se traduciria "good deal"?

Tags: frase

En el sentido de que "that's an amazing deal" cuando se encuentra algo que al contrario del normal es muy asequible, muy rebajado. Lo mejor que se me ocurre sería "es una muy buena oferta" pero no me suena nativo, o ¿esa expresión de verdad tendría sentido? Le agredezco mucho su aporte.

Comment: Hablando con un Cubano últimamente, utilicé *una ganga* para referirme a ‘an amazing deal’ y me dijo que le sonó bien, se ve aqui [great deal](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=a%20great%20deal)

Comment: En México también *una ganga* es la primera cosa que se me ocurre

Answer (score 3):

Depende si es un (1)acuerdo de manos, (2)financiero o de si se refiere a (3)algo barato, una compra.

(1) Buen trato, acuerdo ventajoso, lucrativo, conveniente,
(2) Arreglo económico,  facilidades, buenas condiciones.
(3) Buena oferta, compra ventajosa, ganga, ofertón, ofertazo, precio asequible/abordable.

> Negocio redondo: El que permite obtener las máximas ganancias y todas las ventajas.

Comment: good deal is the same in all cases. The meaning doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Dependerá en todo caso del contexto, no es lo mismo anunciar algo, por ejemplo, en la radio, en un periódico, en televisión que lo digas en una reunión de empresa formal, se lo comuniques a un amigo o trates con la bolsa de valores.

Aunque todas estás formas son extensibles a cualquier ámbito, realmente dependerá de lo que tengas en mente y como lo quieres especificar.

Así "that's an amazing deal", puede traducirse de muchas maneras para indicar lo que en términos generales dices, aunque como digo, siempre dependerá del grado de impresión con el que quieras impactar, pues puede ir de un simple "WOW!, WUAU! o !GUAU!" a un ¡Un buen bocado!, pasando por otras expresiones más habituales, como se han comentado, oferta, chollo, ganga, ¡gran ventaja!, ¡oferta increíble!, ¡oferta impresionante! ¡super oferta!,¡buen trato!, ¡muy barato!, ¡buen negocio!, ¡magnifico trato!, !Acuerdo impresionante! ...

Comment: ! Gracias a ti ! user1234567890000...

Answer (score 1):

#### Chollo

1. m. coloq. Cosa valiosa o apreciable que se adquiere a muy bajo precio o con poco esfuerzo. U. t. en sent. irón. *[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/chollo)*

[image: white to yellow]

<sub>*Fuente de la imagen [chollometro.com](https://www.chollometro.com/ofertas/llegan-los-super-chollos-carrefour-ofertas-en-electronica-electrodomesticos-moda-hogar-y-mas-865253)*</sub>